# How do I prevent my logger from writing multiple instances of a log file?

Tags: java, logging

I wrote a custom logger where the only addition is the following method:

```
public static synchronized Logger getLogger(String name) {
    try {
        boolean append = true;
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("tmp.log", append);
        Logger      log     = Logger.getLogger(name);
        log.addHandler(handler);
        return log;
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(LibraLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(LibraLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return Logger.getLogger(name);
}
```

It produces a series of log files tmp.log, tmp.log.1, tmp.log.2 etc.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Should differently named Loggers log to different files?

Comment: @Will God no. Each class is a separate logger, and therefor would have a file for each class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your logging.properties file check that the  java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit is set to 0.

From the docs:

> java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit
>   specifies an approximate maximum
>   amount to write (in bytes) to any one
>   file. If this is zero, then there is
>   no limit. (Defaults to no limit).
>
> For a rotating set of files, as each
>   file reaches a given size limit, it is
>   closed, rotated out, and a new file
>   opened. Successively older files are
>   named by adding "0", "1", "2", etc
>   into the base filename.

Another possibility is that you are trying to write to the same log file from multiple processes. If the logger detects that a file cannot be opened (It is locked by another process) it will create a new one, by adding the next free number to it.

Comment: I think that's what's happening, even tho the method is synchronized, the logger is detecting the file cannot be opened. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

@badcodenotreat I came across your original question because I had a similar problem and found @Romain Hippeau's solution to helpful too. Now to answer your other question :

" ..even tho the method is synchronized, the logger is detecting the file cannot be opened. Any ideas how to accomplish that?". ...

I implemented my FileHandler in its own separate class utilizing a singleton design pattern so that only one instance of the log file is created and is returned to my main logging application anytime that request is made. Hope that helps.